# After a reading a clojure file line-by-line how to fetch a particular string from particular line?

Tags: file, clojure, readfile

I am new to clojure. I am having trouble as in how to print a particular string after removing special characters and reading a clojure file line-by-line.
I have a file named example.clj which looks like:

```
(defn patient 
"Some string"

(measures 
patient/symptom-fever
patient/symptom-cold
.
.
.
.
patient/symptom-bp))
```

From the above file i have removed all the special characters and reading the file line-by-line with below clojure code.

```
(defn loadcljfile []
  (def newstring(clojure.string/replace (slurp "C:/Users/Desktop/example.clj") #"[\[/.(:)\]-]" " "))
  (with-open [rdr (reader newstring)]
  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
   (println line))))
  (loadcljfile)
```

Now not getting how to print **patient** i.e my defn name and all the **measures**.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Every valid clojure file can be viewed as a data structrue, so it does not make much sense to work with it as with mere line sequence. I should use `org.clojure/tools.reader` here and then walked through this data structure with `specter`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

when defining things with names inside a function it's much safer and easier to use let rather than def. def defines it for the whole namespace (usually the whole file) and let gives something a name just until it's closing ).

I'm this case it makes a lot of sense to let Clojure read the expression and turn it into a data structure for you. you can do this with the load-file function if your file is a function you wish to run or use tools.reader if you just want to have it at a data structure.

if you go the load-file approach you can print it with the clojure.repl/source function and if you go the tools.reader path then you can just print it.